# Single phase appliance on a 3 phase panel?

Tags: hvac, electrical-panel, delta

Can you hook up a *single phase*, 208 / 230V appliance to a *3 phase* panel? The appliance is a RTU/Hvac compressor/condensor for a mini-split (heating/cooling) unit.

The 3 phase panel is: 3 phase, 240V Delta, High leg C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  In a "High/Wild Leg Delta" configuration, you have your choice of 240V or 208V.   Remember always that you **must** use orange wire or phase tape on the "wild leg".

If you want 240V, connect between any phase and any other phase. If you have a lot of 120/240V loads on the panel, it will help phase balance to make one of the phases the wild leg (orange) (i.e. don't just pile everything onto the low phases A and B).

If you want 208V, connect between the wild leg (orange) and the neutral. This helps balance the panel.

Make sure your appliance is insulated for 208V to ground.  If the appliance is only approved for 120/240V with 120V to ground, you must use phase A and B.

Comment: Yeah @ThreePhaseEel, OP's phase numbering is non-standard. And OP if you're wondering about the orange rule, NEC 110.15.

Comment: Yeah -- the OP has the old legacy phase designations that put the high leg on C, I didn't catch that when I went to edit :P

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, thanks. I would love to take one for the team in terms of balancing the phases by using the "wild leg" for one of the phases but I believe that I cannot use a SLASH" rated breaker (120/240) and straight rated 240V breakers are harder to find.

In terms of using the 208V - the appliance doesn't require a neutral - in order to use the 208V I would need a 208Y/120V panel.

Comment: @MV94609 Good catch about the slash rating, you'll need to go to real electrical supply for non-slash 240s.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - yep